# EarlGrey TimeoutException viewDidDisappear

Tags: earlgrey

> Could someone please help me on what needs to be done in case tests fails
>   with kGREYPendingViewsToDisappear as in below case

**Code**

EarlGrey.selectElement(with: grey_keyWindow()).assert(grey_sufficientlyVisible())

**Exception**

UI Test Activity: 
Assertion Failure: EarlGreyTests.swift:27: Exception: TimeoutException

Exception Name: TimeoutException
Exception Reason: Timed out while waiting to perform assertion.
Exception with Assertion: {
  "Assertion Criteria":  "assertWithMatcher:matcherForSufficientlyVisible(>=0.750000)",
  "Element Matcher":  "(kindOfClass('UIWindow') && keyWindow)"
}

Exception Details: Error Trace: [
  {
    "Description":  "Failed to execute block because idling resources below are busy.",
    "Description Glossary":    {
      "GREYAppStateTracker":  "Waiting for viewDidDisappear: call on the view controller. Please ensure that this view controller and it's subclasses call through to their super's implementation.

Full state transition call stack for all objects:
 => Waiting for viewDidDisappear: call on the view controller. Please ensure that this view controller and it's subclasses call through to their super's implementation.
(
    0   EarlGrey                            0x0000000133ea1d3d -[GREYAppStateTrackerObject setState:] + 61
    1   EarlGrey                            0x0000000133e49685 _133-[GREYAppStateTracker grey_changeState:usingOperation:forObject:orInternalObjectDeallocationTracker:orExternalAppStateTrackerObject:]_block_invoke + 1157
    2   EarlGrey                            0x0000000133e48858 -[GREYAppStateTracker grey_performBlockInCriticalSection:] + 328
    3   EarlGrey                            0x0000000133e490ab -[GREYAppStateTracker grey_changeState:usingOperation:forObject:orInternalObjectDeallocationTracker:orExternalAppStateTrackerObject:] + 1371
    4   EarlGrey                            0x0000000133e4710c -[GREYAppStateTracker untrackState:forObject:] + 92
    5   EarlGrey                            0x0000000133e4dea7 -[UIViewController(GREYAdditions) greyswizzled_viewDidAppear:] + 135
    6   EarlGreyTests                       0x0000000133bf86c6 -[UIViewController(FIRAScreenClassName) fira_viewDidAppear:] + 33
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000136d4a9ae -[UIViewControllerAccessibility viewDidAppear:] + 67
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000110ee1e5f -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 697
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000110ee23ad _52-[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:]_block_invoke + 265
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000115310553 -[_NSArrayI enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 163
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000110ee2067 -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 1217
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000110ee23ad _52-[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:]_block_invoke + 265
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001153c256a -[_NSSingleObjectArrayI enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 58
    14  UIKit                               0x0000000110ee2067 -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 1217
    15  UIKit                               0x0000000110ee28f0 -[UIViewController _endAppearanceTransition:] + 197
    16  UIKit                               0x0000000110f1aebd -[UINavigationController navigationTransitionView:didEndTransition:fromView:toView:] + 1287
    17  UIKit                               0x0000000136d611aa -[UINavigationControllerAccessibility navigationTransitionView:didEndTransition:fromView:toView:] + 102
    18  UIKit                               0x0000000111296db1 -[UINavigationTransitionView _notifyDelegateTransitionDidStopWithContext:] + 421
    19  UIKit                               0x0000000111297072 -[UINavigationTransitionView _cleanupTransition] + 605
    20  UIKit                               0x0000000110dccea9 -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 343
    21  UIKit                               0x0000000110dc8546 +[UIViewAnimationState popAnimationState] + 319
    22  UIKit                               0x0000000111296b20 -[UINavigationTransitionView transition:fromView:toView:] + 2571
    23  UIKit                               0x0000000110f2411f -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 3261
    24  UIKit                               0x0000000110f2461e -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 870
    25  UIKit                               0x0000000110f2586c -[UINavigationController _viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 150
    26  UIKit                               0x000000011117dd0b -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 231
    27  UIKit                               0x0000000136d7e61c -[UILayoutContainerViewAccessibility layoutSubviews] + 42
    28  UIKit                               0x0000000110e077a8 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1515
    29  QuartzCore                          0x00000001161bd456 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 177
    30  QuartzCore                          0x00000001161c1667 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 395
    31  QuartzCore                          0x00000001161480fb _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 343
    32  QuartzCore                          0x000000011617579c _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 568
    33  UIKit                               0x0000000110d52269 _34-[UIApplication _firstCommitBlock]_block_invoke_2 + 141
    34  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000115324b0c _CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK_ + 12
    35  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001153092db _CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 331
    36  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000115308a84 _CFRunLoopRun + 1284
    37  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011530830b CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 635
    38  GraphicsServices                    0x000000011a536a73 GSEventRunModal + 62
    39  UIKit                               0x0000000110d38057 UIApplicationMain + 159
    40  MyApp                                0x000000010e56c9b7 main + 55
    41  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000117a65955 start + 1
)
"
    },
    "Error Domain":  "com.google.earlgrey.GREYUIThreadExecutorErrorDomain",
    "Error Code":  "0",
    "File Name":  "GREYUIThreadExecutor.m",
    "Function Name":  "-[GREYUIThreadExecutor executeSyncWithTimeout:block:error:]",
    "Line":  "239",
    "TestCase Class":  "EarlGreyTests.EarlGreyTests",
    "TestCase Method":  "testExample"
  },
  {
    "Description":  "Failed to execute assertion within 30 seconds.",
    "Error Domain":  "com.google.earlgrey.ElementInteractionErrorDomain",
    "Error Code":  "4",
    "File Name":  "GREYElementInteraction.m",
    "Function Name":  "-[GREYElementInteraction assert:error:]",
    "Line":  "450",
    "TestCase Class":  "EarlGreyTests.EarlGreyTests",
    "TestCase Method":  "testExample"
  }
]

**What work around didn't work**

Adding viewDidDisappear in FeedItemCollectionViewController

Comment: Is the viewDidDisappear calling [super viewDidDisappear]?

Comment: Yes its calling all the way till UIViewController

Comment: There's no other idling resource that's failing in the error logs?